# MySQL: combining multiple WHERE clauses from same table with diff column names

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am new to MySQL and am learning via PluralSight. I am trying to execute a query with the result 4 columns. 3 of the 4 columns are coming from the same column, but are distinguished by a WHERE clause directed to a numeric value. Additionally, I am including a column from a different table. I feel like the fix is very easy, but as I mentioned, I am new to this. Individually, the sections work great, but I do not know how to properly join them. Any help would be appreciated. My work thus far is included below.

```
Select answer as FirstName
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_answers
WHERE plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 1

Select answer as MI
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_answers
WHERE plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 54 

Select answer as LastName
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_answers
WHERE plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 55

Select request_date
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_forms_answers
```

Comment: I guess you need to get 4 columns at the end. How will you detect which `FirstName` match to any `LastName`? I mean, you should get some other field, I suspect something like `FormId` or something else, otherwise it makes no sense

Comment: That is a fair point. The person over the database is out and I do not have column IDs so I am working a bit blindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not an answer**

Since I suspect you are missing something important in your requirements

I want just provide you an approach of what you want to get, th only thing you are missing is `GROUP BY` column.

```
SELECT
   IF(plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 1,answer, null) as FirstName
   IF(plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 54,answer, null) as MI,
   IF(plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 55,answer, null) as LastName,
   request_date
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_answers
WHERE plugin_formcreator_questions_id IN (1,54,55)
```

So the final version should be something like:

```
SELECT
   form_id,
   MAX(IF(plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 1,answer, null)) as FirstName
   MAX(IF(plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 54,answer, null)) as MI,
   MAX(IF(plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 55,answer, null)) as LastName,
   MAX(request_date)
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_answers
WHERE plugin_formcreator_questions_id IN (1,54,55)
GROUP BY form_id
```

Comment: I believe this will also help me, as I believe the database is missing a few pieces of information. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to incorporate:

Select request_date
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_forms_answers
WHERE plugin_formcreator_forms_answers_id = glpi_plugin_formcreator_forms_answers.id

Comment: @CillyC just replace `form_id` in my query with `id` in both cases when `SELECT` and when `GROUP BY` I guess

Answer (score 0):

We generally use union when we have multiple where clause.you can use UNION clause.For this

`Select answer as FirstName
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_answers
WHERE plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 1
UNION
Select answer as MI
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_answers
WHERE plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 54 
UNION
Select answer as LastName
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_answers
WHERE plugin_formcreator_questions_id = 55
UNION
Select request_date
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_forms_answers`

Comment: My first thought was to use UNION, however, it becomes a mega-column. :/ Do you have any sources that may help explain UNION a little better?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select case when plugin_formcreator_questions_id=1 then answer end as FirstName,
case when plugin_formcreator_questions_id=54 then answer end as MI,
case when plugin_formcreator_questions_id=55 then answer end as LastName
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_answers
```

Comment: This did help me achieve the multiple columns! Thank you. How should I go about incorporating the final section:

Select request_date
FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_formcreator_forms_answers

Comment: to which table you want to incorporate ? and if answers worked for you then please accept my ans

Comment: it will be great if you give some table data in your question , then it will be easy to understand

Comment: The table I am wanting to create will join answers from a form to automate user account creation. ID 1 is first name, ID 54 is middle initial, ID 55 is the last name and the fourth column is for date requested from the form.